# Coding email signature using style tags after each element?

Tags: html, css, email, styles

I have to code an email signature and I've never done it before and am fairly new to coding. I have an example in which the style tags are listed directly after each element instead of having  tags independently. For example:

```
td style="border-right:1px solid rgb(223,223,223);">
    <div style="height:42px;">
        <div style="float:left;">
            <p style="font-size:18px; margin:0; color:#187984; font-weight:bold;">example</p>
```

I'm more used to using style tags. Is there a benefit to doing it in the example code above? Can I use style tags instead? Will this affect whether it is compatible in different email clients?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When coding for email, all (almost) of your HTML should be kept "inline" - in the style of your sample code above. This is because certain email providers strip CSS from the head of your html (Gmail for one).

```
<td style="font-family:Ariel; font-size:17px; line-height:20px; color:#000001; font-weight:normal; text-decoration:none; text-align:left;">Hello</td>
```